# How to get to daemon source?

Tags: android

I'm performing static analysis on system framework code, and some of the interesting ones seem to be talking to daemons via sockets. How do I get to the source of the daemons to see what they do with the data being sent over? I suppose these are C code rather than java? Do the binaries reside as ELF binaries somewhere or compiled into a library? How do I figure it out?

Thanks!

Comment: is it linux or windows ?

Comment: @ws going by the tag, Android

Comment: Yes sorry for not mentioning, it's Android system framework on a Samsung Galaxy S6 device.